# How do I use an API key/secret on Binance's TestNet?

Tags: python, binance, binance-smart-chain, binance-api-client

Following the instructions here, https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/wallet/arkane.html, I created a Binance SmartChain account with its "0x" prefixed wallet address.  I then added funds.  What I can't figure out is how I get a TestNet API key and secret so that I can test my Python API calls.  I create the client like so

```
from binance.client import Client
...
auth_client = Client(key, b64secret)
 if account.testing:
    auth_client.API_URL = 'https://testnet.binance.vision/api'
```

How do I get an API key tied to my Binance SmartChain address?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your API credentials from [here](https://testnet.binance.vision/) and pass the testnet variable into the Client constructor. See the
[documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=client#binance.client.Client.__init__).

```py
auth_client = Client(key, b64secret, testnet=True)
```

does the job.